# Oracle, php - add action in form

Tags: php, html, oracle

I'm trying to make this button checking if Employee ID passing via textbox exsits in Oracle Database and depend on result - show YES or NO after ':'.

[image]

But i have absolutely no idea how. I tried to make a form in a form:

```
<form action="addemp.php" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Employee ID: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="empid" size=1/> 
    <form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="check" value="Check?"> :
    </form>
```

But no success since It can not be done. 
Any suggestions?
EDIT:

check.php

```
<?php

     $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr', 'hr');
      $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select count(*) from employees where employee_id=TO_NUMBER(".$_GET['idprac'].")");
     oci_execute($stid);
    $result = oci_num_rows($stid);
    // Use this $empId and check in query.

    if($result==1){
      echo "free";
    } else 
    {
      echo "owned";
    }

    ?>
```

code in index.html

```
    <td><input type="text" name="idprac" size=1/> 
    <input type="button" name="check" class='checkEmp' value="Check?"> : <span class='showResult'></span>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.checkEmp').click(function(){
    var empId= $('#idprac').val();
    $.ajax({url:"check.php?idprac="+empId,cache:false,success:function(result){
      $('.showResult').html(result);
    }});
  });
</script>
```

But ajax does not want to pass parameter to check.php (undefined error) and if i set `var empID = whatever number` gives me always 'owned'.

Comment: Nested `<form>` are not allowed.

Comment: Check through AJAX.

Comment: @NanaPartykar thank you for your birlliant answer. Since I learned myself as i wrote "since It can not be done" - so againg thanks -.-

Comment: Show your **check.php** code @Michal

Comment: Atleast respond to the answer given below @Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Nested `<form>` are **NOT** allowed.

2) To check employee exist or not. Use **Ajax**.

```
<form action="addemp.php" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Employee ID: </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id='empId' name="empid" size=1/> 
        <input type="button" name="check" class='checkEmp' value="Check?"> : <span class='showResult'></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.checkEmp').click(function(){
    var empId= $('#empId').val();
    $.ajax({url:"check.php?empId="+empId,cache:false,success:function(result){
      $('.showResult').html(result);
    }});
  });
</script>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
$empId = $_GET['empId'];

// Use this $empId and check in query.

if(employee id is available){
  echo "Yes";
} else {
  echo "No";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank You - it is very helpuf. but still i have some erros. I Have edited my post.

Comment: You have missed `id` in <input>. Use `<input type="text" id='idprac' name="idprac" size=1/> ` @MichałM

Comment: *All My Pleasure.* I don't want anyone stop coding because of issues. Keep Asking Stack Overflow. You Will definitely Get Help. *Be Safe. Keep Coding* @MichałM